# Create an animated treemap that has whitespace as total decreases

Tags: r, treemap

I want to create an animated treemap like this: https://worldbank.tumblr.com/post/160190938786/how-has-the-number-of-people-living-in-extreme that changes that actual size of total (or size of each individual box), not just the proportion and allows for white space.

```
pacman::p_load(treemapify, ggplot2,  gganimate)
p<-ggplot(df, aes(
  area = value, 
  fill = Region, 
  label = abbrev, 
  subgroup = Region, 
  subgroup2=abbrev)) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap(layout = "fixed") + 
  geom_treemap_subgroup_border(layout = "fixed") +
  geom_treemap_subgroup2_border(layout = "fixed") +
  geom_treemap_subgroup2_text(layout = "fixed") +
  transition_time(scenario) +
  ease_aes('year')
anim_save("treemap.gif", p, nframes = 30, height = 550, width = 550)
```

I've tried creating a dummy category/subgroup to create whitespace, but that's not exactly what I want.

Comment: You need to make a reproducible example, including an example of what `df` is.